# Higher idle after throttle body cleaning in 2009 rav4

Tags: idle, fast-idle

I had idle issues so I cleaned the throttle body after noticing quite a lot of carbon buildup.
Before cleaning the normal idle was 700, but now it idles at 950 and increases to 1050 when taken out of drive into park.
I made sure not to adjust the position of the throttle plate by hand as I heard that can damage it. Instead, I got a friend to press on the accelerator whilst the ignition was on. Further, I did not remove any vacuum lines.
I also tried the idle relearn procedure for the car. It seemed to help but it returned back to normal once I turned off the car.
My questions are: Is this normal after cleaning the throttle body? Is it caused by additional airflow due to the lack of carbon? Will it return back to normal with time?

The car has no codes and runs perfectly find except for the high idle.

Comment: Remove idle speed control valve and clean it with throttle body cleaner.

Comment: This car does not have a IAC valve. It has electronic throttle control.

Comment: If I remember correctly (which I rarely do), I made this same mistake not too long ago. You might want to look at some other threads. I think there was progress made there. Otherwise, a vacuum leak could cause this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the electronic drive by wire system; electric throttle driven by a servo motor controlled by the ecm being fed input signals from the electronic pedal. The pedal is the master, the ecm interprets pedal signals to command the electric servo motor to open/close throttle. No adjustments are possible and this model has a self calibration mode when invoked; turning on ignition without touching the pedal, waiting for 30 seconds as the ecm detects no starting and zero pedal movement before entering throttle calibration mode. Total time from ignition on time is about one minute. Cycle the ignition switch off then restart. This is for GM EFI systems using drive by wire systems.

I don't know if Toyotas have a similar program. One way to find out is finding Toyota forums and asking members with the same model. They may have better info.

I'm confused that you state there's an adjustment for throttle position. It would be wiser to find out more about idle rpm issues before guessing on mechanical throttle adjustments.